# django filter queryset based on __str__ of model

Tags: python, django, filter, django-queryset

I have the following model:

```
class Subspecies(models.Model):
    species = models.ForeignKey(Species)
    subspecies = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.species.species_english+" "+self.species.species+" "+self.subspecies

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.species.species_english+" "+self.species.species+" "+self.subspecies
```

Notice that the ForeignKey field, `species` is used in the `__str__` and `__unicode__` methods.  I had made this filter query:

```
l = list(Subspecies.objects.filter(subspecies__contains=request.GET.get('term')).order_by('subspecies')[:10])
```

This is almost what I want, except not quite.  What I really want is a filter that checks if the `__str__` representation of the object contains some group of characters, instead of just checking the `subspecies` field.  Instead of `subspecies__contains=...` it would be something like `__str____contains=...` but of course that doesn't work.

Is this possible?  IF so how would I make this query?

Thanks!

Comment: why can't you just filter on the three fields in the related model?

Comment: Yes that is what I ended up doing, I would rather be able to search the whole phrase together, but filtering separately with OR is almost OK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Filter generates a query to be executed in DB.

`__str__` is run in Python interpreter. You can't call it from DB.
SO the short answer is "no, you can't". You have to filter it manually, using `filter` built-in function, for example.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I was afraid of that.  This model contains like 20K rows.  I tried this in the shell, but took quite some time.  `[i for i in Subspecies.objects.all() if 'aur' in unicode(i)]` The DB filter method is very quick.  Probably will be too slow for the web.

Comment: similar poor performance with: `a = filter(lambda x: 'aur' in unicode(x), s.objects.all())` :-/

Comment: You can use raw SQL expression to make such a query, smth like `... WHERE species_english || species || subspecies CONTAINS ...`

Comment: I noticed there is a way to write SQL in there.  to get it exactly i could use `concat` to combine the fields to one string.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best approach I found here is to mark your target with a quotation (' ').  then slice the string and filter based on it .. here is how it goes in your case

```
class Subspecies(models.Model):
    species = models.ForeignKey(Species)
    subspecies = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __str__(self):
    return self.species.species_english+" "+self.species.species+" "+" 'str(self.subspecies)'"

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.species.species_english+" "+self.species.species+" "+" 'str(self.subspecies)'"
```

As you see your `subspecies` part now are between ' '

Then you do the next to filter based on it :

```
sub_input = request.GET.get('term')
sub = sub_input .split("'")[1::2] #not sure how did [1::2] works but it is the only way that worked for me 
l = Subspecies.objects.filter(subspecie=sub[0]) #used indexing as split gives you result as a list
```